# CVBuffer is nil in call back of h264 decoder

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, h.264, video-toolbox

When i try to decode the raw h264 stream , CVBuffer gives me nil on callback, and this only happen on the real device(iPhone , iPad) and not on the simulator.
Any suggestions?!

Comment: Show your code, please

Answer (score 0):

Found this ffmpeg ticket, which, after debugging, seems to be caused by the same issue (nil CVBuffer, status -12909) -  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9016#trac-add-comment

So far no resolution -- and the same code works on Intel Macos (broken on M1). It is broken across both iPhone and iPad with iOS 15, but the same code worked on the same devices with iOS 14.x.

P.S. Also https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9713